# How can I fix this problem?

Tags: r

> convert_counts <- function(x)

- {
- ```
  x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
  ```
- ```
  x <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c(""No"", ""Yes""))
  ```

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
x <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c(""No"

> ```
> return(x)
> ```

Error: object 'x' not found

> }
> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Please ask programming questions on https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotation marks around the `Yes` and `No` labels in the `factor` function. In R you use single quotation marks around text to denote it as a string. Changing the quotation marks from double to single fixes the error.

```
convert_counts <- function(x){
  x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
  x <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes"))
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: Thank you  so much !